# How can I test dialogflow from detect intent API in python?

Tags: python, nlp, dialogflow-es

I made an agent with a knowledge base and documents in it using dialogflow console.
know I want to test it form a python code from my computer how can I code the query to get the response?

Comment: you need to use https://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and you can connect with your dialogflow and use functions to detect intent.

Comment: I tried to understand them they are a nightmary, toooo long to understand.

Comment: please if you can give me a piece of code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following official python package and install using `pip`.

`pip install google-cloud-dialogflow`

Check out the quickstart on the official google cloud documentation to detect the intent and retrieve the response.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/api

Comment: Thanks that was helpful, but it didn't work.

Comment: The response that i got was not from the knowledge base that i created, it was as if the bot was new.

Comment: Are you able to test the agent correctly in the web console? If you have multiple agents under one account, specify the agent id.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below links for code as you required. this has multiple links which can help you to understand flow.

- https://cloudacademy.com/blog/how-to-build-an-intelligent-chatbot-with-python-and-dialogflow/
- https://dev.to/mrkanthaliya/build-intelligent-chatbot-using-dialogflow-54nh
- https://medium.com/zenofai/creating-chatbot-using-python-flask-d6947d8ef805
- https://chatbotslife.com/dialogflow-tutorial-back-functionality-in-chatbot-using-python-django-eb2ce921dd19

Answer (score 0):

this is a code can solve the problem

```
def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, texts, language_code):
    """Returns the result of detect intent with texts as inputs.

    Using the same `session_id` between requests allows continuation
    of the conversation."""
    from google.cloud import dialogflow_v2beta1

    session_client = dialogflow_v2beta1.SessionsClient()

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
    print("Session path: {}\n".format(session))

    #for text in texts:
    text_input = dialogflow_v2beta1.TextInput(text=text, language_code=language_code)

    query_input = dialogflow_v2beta1.QueryInput(text=text_input)

    response = session_client.detect_intent(
        request={"session": session, "query_input": query_input}
    )

    print("=" * 20)
    print("Query text: {}".format(response.query_result.query_text))
    print(
        "Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})\n".format(
            response.query_result.intent.display_name,
            response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence,
        )
    )
    print("Fulfillment text: {}\n".format(response.query_result.fulfillment_text))
```

***my problem I was importing and using the normal dialogflow instead of using dialogflow_v2beta1 because using knowledge base is a beta feature.***